# Open an image with Paint per command / function

Tags: python

I think the title sums it up pretty good, but I want to open a .gif file with paint when pressing a button. The .gif file is in the Project Folder.

Comment: you must show us your code effort, before getting any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use inbuilt library os for this.

You can run system commands with

```
os.system("some command")
```

Paint has a command which opens up the file. You can use this to load the file in paint automatically

1. Relative path

```
os.system("mspaint filename.gif")
```

2. Absolute path

```
os.system("mspaint C:/.../filename.gif") #Full path
```

And of course, you can generate this arg like any other string. So you can load it up dynamically